# Grab random entry without orderby="random"?

Tags: orderby, channel-videos, random

I'm using DevDemon's Channel Videos to include videos into my entry. I'd like to output only up to 2 videos, randomly selected from my list. Unfortunately the orderby="random" option isn't available. Is there another way to easily accomplish this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to output your Channel Video tag loop into a Stash list, using `{stash:set_list}`, then you could pull a random subset out via `{stash:get_list orderby="random" limit="2"}`.

Here are links, for more info: [Stash Set List](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3astash%3aset_list%7D) and [Stash Get List](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3astash%3aget_list%7D). There also are lots of Stash list examples here on the EE Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the total number of returned results (say, 10 videos) you could probably use one of the two add-ons below to return a random number in that range for a {if count == "3"} conditional?

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/random-between

or

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-random

Just thinking outside the box with no experience with Channel Videos.

Comment: Lottor-ee works super well in this scenario too! http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-lottoree Lots of favorites as well! Whenever I'm looking for a new add-on I always look to see how many favorites it has :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answers. In the end Stash looks like the most direct solution. Though it's nice to know those other random generators exist--I was close to trying out low_random just for the heck of it since it looks so useful.

Here's my stash code btw

```
        {exp:stash:set_list name="videos" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:channel_videos:videos entry_id="{entry_id}" embed_width="300" embed_height="169"}
       {stash:embed_code}{video:embed_code}{/stash:embed_code}
            {/exp:channel_videos:videos}
        {/exp:stash:set_list}

        {exp:stash:get_list name="videos" orderby="random" limit="2"}
           {embed_code}
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
```